# WPF Window непонятная ширина при WindowState.Maximized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

У меня монитор разрешением 1920х1200

```
SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth=1920
SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width=1920
```

подписываемся на изменение размера окна

```
win.SizeChanged += SizeChanged;
```

и в SizeChanged получаем что e.NewSize.Width=1936

Откуда такое число?

зы: Подозреваю, что это ширина бордюра 8*2+1920(видимая часть), которое просто "за пределами экрана", но это звучит как бред.

Comment: `Maximized` наверное?

Answer (score 1):

> Подозреваю, что это ширина бордюра 8*2+1920(видимая часть), которое
>   просто "за пределами экрана", но это звучит как бред.

[Так и есть.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150304-00/?p=44543)

Ширина бордюров в неразвернутом окне включается в его размер. Например, если вы установите следующие параметры окна в XAML:

```
Left="0"
Top="0"
Width="1920"
```

то на Windows 7 увидите окно с бордюрами, а на Windows 10 -- зазоры между окном и краем экрана (потому что бордюры в десятке сделали прозрачными).

Когда же окно разворачивается на весь экран, то на экране отображается только "клиентская" часть окна, а бордюры при этом уходят за границы экрана. Отсюда и "странный" размер окна.

Comment: а как же мне тогда узнать ширину бордюра для правильных расчетов? ведь у окна может быть разный стиль.

Comment: @vitidev на Win7 я смог получить значение 8 так: `SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth + SystemParameters.FixedFrameVerticalBorderWidth + SystemParameters.BorderWidth`. Но подозреваю, что возвращаемые этими свойствами значения могут варьироваться в зависимости от системы, включенного/выключенного Aero и т.д. [Вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6032327/1985167) предлагают вроде как универсальный способ, попробуйте.